# Jquery: Get each image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I have a series of images each with the class "photo";

I want to go through each of these and retrieve the photo source, for use later in an if statement. I have written the below code to do this, but have not been successful:

```
$.each($(".photo"), function() {
  var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src").length;
  console.log(imgsrc);
});
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong here. It seems to make sense to me, but I dont get anything in the console.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: just avoid the `length` you are good to go

Comment: @ubercooluk thanks but its seems to make no difference whether I use it or not

Comment: `.photo` is the class of the image..can you doublecheck that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have given same class name for all img tag then try this ,

```
  $(".photo").each(function() {  
   imgsrc = this.src;
   console.log(imgsrc);
  });
```

Comment: Why we can't use imgsrc = this.attr('src')? it throws me an error

Comment: this.attr('src') doesn't work because "this" isn't jQuerified yet: to fix that, do

`$(this).attr('src)`

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".photo").each(function() {  
       imgsrc = this.src;
       console.log(imgsrc);
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are missing `doc ready handler`:

```
$(function(){
  $.each($(".photo"), function() {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src").length;
    console.log(imgsrc); // logging length it should now print the length
  });
});
```

make sure to load this script first then your `$.each()` function:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the `lenght` of an object / array out of context here :

```
var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src").length;
```

change to

```
var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
```

**edit** : in order to check if the attribute exists

```
if (imgsrc == undefined) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: surely that would still work though? It would just give me a number instead of a string. I have length there because I want to make and if statement later on eg: if(imgsrc < 1)

Comment: you can still make that statement, `if (imgsrc == undefined)`, see updated answer